# Efficient way to implement MapKit in a viewController that is push on Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to add a mapKit in a viewController in IB that I am pushing on top of my navigation controller but no matter where in the cycle I add the annotations it seems like the whole thing causes a delay and until mapKit is not rendered the scrollview that contains everything doesn't scroll easily. Is there a way to do this in iOS similar to Android in the background threads for instance?

Below is the code even without adding any annotation, rendering is still causing the delay. I'm pretty sure there's another way. Any idea?

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController , MKMapViewDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.mapView?.delegate = self
    }


      //changing the annotation
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
                return nil
            }
            let reuseId = "detailMrker"
            var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
            if anView == nil {
                anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                anView?.image = UIImage(named:"location.png")
                anView?.canShowCallout = true
            }
            else {
                anView?.annotation = annotation
            }
            return anView
        }

}
```

Comment: Show your real code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN render a VC ahead of time, and present it from offscreen, with a modal presentation. If you absolutely must push from your UINavigationController, then you're stuck waiting for the VC to call the draw methods of its view, after the VC is pushed.

There are other things you can do ahead of time, however. Use something other than DetailFeedViewController as your CLLocationManagerDelegate, and MKMapDelegate. If you do so, you can get the user's location, set the map coordinates, and add you annotation, before the VC is pushed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By rendering a VC aeahd of time , do you mean something like instantialting a view controller and then just present(vc...) ?

Comment: There are different ways to handle it and it's involved; otherwise I'd provide an example. Basically, a VC's view property can be treated like any other UIView: its draw methods can be called, etc.... let myVC = UIViewController() ONLY calls viewDidLoad, so you'll have to do more work. Look into animateWithDuration and modal presentation.

Comment: Also, and this is the important part, MKMapKit is generally not slower because its more visually detailed, but because it requires data from the cellular device or GPS. I'd bet that the second half of my answer will be more helpful. I can possibly find you some of my examples, if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks again, if you could post something rather than words would be great, not that your replies aren't but I can understand code better I guess. 
Also, I just came across MKMapSnapshotter() which seems to be a great solution here if I can manage to get it to work; it basically provides an image of the map rather than the map itself which then I could load that image seamlesly and I guess with much better performance. Thanks

Comment: Here's a game I worked on a while back. My partner backed out, so feel free to use whatever. Notice that my CLLocationManager is a singleton, meaning that I can start accessing the user's location when I start the app (or whenever). You could do the same thing with the MKMapKit and delegate, and have all of your location info ready to go, before the actual view loads:
https://github.com/dylanthelion/AssassinationClient/tree/develop

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll take a look to get an idea. I am not a fan of singleton and in my case it's not really only one location (user's) to get and could be multiple locations. But it's still good. 
I'm still thinking of snapshotted .. sounds like a cool idea to me so far .. Anyways, I'll accept your answer tomorrow if nothing else more specific shows up.